# Simple Mutation with a Probability

Tags: python, random, probability, genetic-algorithm, dplyr

As per the section of code below, I am trying to implement an automatic and random mutation process.

```
data = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]

data[random.randint(0,len(data)-1)]=random.randrange(0,1)

print(data)
```

The code is an adaptation of some other posts I have found, although it is randomly mutating a value every time with either a 0 or 1. I require this to occur with only a certain probability (such as a 0.05 chance of mutation) rather than always being guaranteed.

Additionally, often a 0 is being replaced with a 0 and therefore there is no change to the output, so I would like to limit it in a way that a 0 will only mutate to a 1 and a 1 mutates to a 0.

I would really appreciate the assistance in resolving these two issues.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: omg... not only did you use `randint` where you should've used `randrange`, but you managed to also use `randrange` when you should've used `randint` instead. You *always* write a zero.

Comment: "Additionally, often a 0 is being replaced with a 0 and therefore there is no change to the output, so I would like to limit it in a way that a 0 will only mutate to a 1 and a 1 mutates to a 0." About half the time, yes? Maybe you can think of a rule that will tell you what probability to use for setting the value, that accounts for the possibility that setting the value doesn't actually flip it?

Comment: Anyway, did you try [looking at the documentation for the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to try to find something that does what you want? Or maybe you can think of a way to translate, for example, "a random number between 0 and 1", into "an X probability of something happening"? (Hint: what is the largest possible value a probability could have? What is the smallest possible value a probability could have?

Comment: @superbrain thanks for drawing my attention to that. I'm pretty new to coding in general and my understanding is quite basic even with the help of the documentation, so I guess in trying to adapt other code I got them mixed around. Will look into it more and keep it in mind. Cheers!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I appreciate the suggestions and ways of thinking about the problem. I did take a look, but now that I have a better understanding I will go through it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following:

For each element in `data`, mutate it (`1 - val`) only if a random value generated by `random()` function is less than the defined mutation probability.

For example:

```
import random

mutation_prob = 0.05

data = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

mutated_data = [1 - x if random.random() < mutation_prob else x for x in data]
```

If the mutation should be decided regarding the data as a whole, you can do:

```
mutation_prob = 0.05

data = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

do_mutation = random.random() < mutation_prob
mutated_data = [1 - x if do_mutation else x for x in data]
```

Comment: Here, every position has the chance of 5% to mutate, not only one random position. The question isn't entirely clear in that regard, though. It might be exactly what they wanted.

Comment: @Wups I'd say if that's what they wanted, they wouldn't have gone through the trouble of picking a random index to change...

Comment: @Wups changed my solution for both cases. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I appreciate you providing and explaining both options, and @Wups this is a really good point - thanks for raising it! The first approach is pretty much what I am after as I would like to only change the indices individually rather than the whole set of data.

Answer (score 3):

Resume

- mutate any value with a choosen probability
- randomly choose the position
- when the position is choosen, switch between `0` and `1`

```
def mutate(data, proba=0.05):
    if random.random() < proba:
        data[random.randrange(len(data))] ^= 1    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    for i in range(10):
        mutate(data)
        print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you mind explaining what the `range(10)` does?

Comment: @Gfizz that is just for demo purpose, to show 10 possible try of mutations

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def changeData(data):
  seed = random.randint(0,1000)
  # probability of 0.05 (50 / 1000)
  if seed <= 50:
     indexToChange = random.randint(0,len(data)-1)
  # change 0 with 1 and viceversa
     data[indexToChange] = 1 if data[indexToChange]  == 0 else 0
 
if __name__== '__main__':
   data = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
   for i in range(0,100):
     changeData(data)
   print(data)
```